# New Client for Identity Server

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine

I am trying to create new client using `client_credentails` grant but i am unable to do that

```
{
                "ClientId": "integrations",
                "ClientSecrets": [ "secret", "2BB80D537B1DA3E38BD30361AA855686BDE0EACD7162FEF6A25FE97BF527A25B" ],
                "AllowedGrantTypes": [
                    "client_credentials"
                ],
                "AccessTokenType": 0,
                "AccessTokenLifetimeInSeconds": 3600,
                "IdentityTokenLifetimeInSeconds": 3600,
                "RequireClientSecret": true,
                "AllowedScopes": [
                    "openid",
                    "dataEventRecords",
                    "dataeventrecordsscope",
                    "securedFiles",
                    "securedfilesscope",
                    "role",
                    "EngineAPI",
                    "postman_api"
                ]
            }
```

api returns `"error": "invalid_client"`
I am not sure what should be in ClientSecrets. Plain text or SHA256?
What do I miss in configuration?

Comment: where do you have this settings ? is it appsettings.json from identityserver?

Comment: yes i added new client there

Comment: Aren't you missing these settings in your client definition: ClientName, RedirectUris, PostLogoutRedirectUris and AllowedCorsOrigins? Have you sort this problem out? @user1075940